# can't click checkbox in Chrome with Selenium

Tags: javascript, jquery, selenium

```
<div class="oj-checkboxset-wrapper">
                        <span class="oj-choice-row oj-enabled oj-selected">
                            <label class="oj-checkbox-label oj-enabled oj-selected oj-active" for="padding" style="max-width: 70%"><span class="oj-radiocheckbox-label-text"><span class="oj-radiocheckbox-label-text">Zero-padding</span><span class="oj-radiocheckbox-icon"></span></span><span class="oj-radiocheckbox-icon"></span></label>
                            <input data-tabmod="-1" tabindex="-1" placeholder="" class="oj-checkbox oj-component oj-enabled oj-component-initnode oj-selected" id="padding" value="Y" type="checkbox">

                        </span>
                    </div>
```

the checkbox Zero-padding actually is visible, but can't click on it. got exception like this org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException:element not visible

i tried many tricky ways , but did not work:( any idea will be appreciated. thanks in advance!

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='padding']")); 
element.click();

String js = "arguments[0].style.height='auto'; arguments[0].style.visibility='visible';";
((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript(js, elem);

Actions action = new Actions(driver);          action.moveToElement(element).sendKeys(Keys.SPACE).build().perform();
```

Comment: Did you try using the `#padding` query instead of this xpath query?

Comment: There shouldn't be any need to use xpath when you are locating on an ID, as there should always be one of them on the page anyway. Try `driver.findElement(By.id('padding'));`

Comment: Also - are you taking a screenshot on failure? It could be that the element is not within the visible viewport of the selenium window.

Comment: Thank you guys for quick response! i also tried By.id, but unlucky, it did not work, 
driver.findElement(By.id("padding")).click();
as the checkbox has style="max-width: 70%", not sure if this causes the issue?